# how to make round image border to imageview programatically android

Tags: android

I want to make round image by code with gradiant color like this picture[image]

Comment: You can use **RoundedImageView Library**...

Comment: but i want make border with 3 colors or put the border as image drawable as picture shows , not one color for the border , i tried all off this answers before

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check this solution https://github.com/vinc3m1/RoundedImageView
It works for me.

Example with border:

```
        <RoundedImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageViewAvatar"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
            android:background="@drawable/border"
            android:cropToPadding="true"
            android:padding="7dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            my:is_oval="true"
            my:round_background="false" />
```

Where border is your png with any border you want. All you need is set padding, that wiil be a distance between your image and border. And Set the image, of course.

Comment: but i want make border with 3 colors or put the border as image drawable as picture shows , not one color for the border , i tried all off this answers before

Comment: You can use RoundedImageView for round image and make border separately as you want. For example, use RoundedImageView and ImageView(for border) in RelativeLayout.

Comment: Can u put example with code plz

Comment: See my edited answer. It's better, than use two ImageViews.

Comment: thanks that what i need , i used this padding and background border  with imageview , u saved my day

Answer (score 0):

this is an Lib for android u can use this https://github.com/pungrue26/SelectableRoundedImageView

Comment: but i want make border with 3 colors or put the border as image drawable as picture shows , not one color for the border , i tried all off this answers before

Answer (score 0):

You can use [RoundedImageView](https://github.com/vinc3m1/RoundedImageView) library.

Or, take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2459916/2504200) if you don't want to use a library.

Comment: but i want make border with 3 colors as picture shows , not one color for the border , i tried all off this answers before