# Add border to ImageView Android with Universal Image Loader

Tags: android, android-imageview, universal-image-loader

I would like to add a border (white) around my ImageView.

Here is the code of the layout :

```
<ImageView
                android:id="@+id/detail_annonce_image_user"
                android:layout_width="65dp"
                android:layout_height="65dp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="225dp"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/avatar1" />
```

And here is the JAVA code :

```
    options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
            .displayer(new RoundedBitmapDisplayer(2000))
            .cacheOnDisc(true)
            .build();

if (avatarUser.contains("avatar") == true) {
    if (avatarUser.equals("avatar1")) {
        imageUser_txt.setImageResource(R.drawable.avatar1) ;
    }
    else if (avatarUser.equals("avatar2")) {
        imageUser_txt.setImageResource(R.drawable.avatar2) ;
    }
    else if (avatarUser.equals("avatar3")) {
        imageUser_txt.setImageResource(R.drawable.avatar3) ;
    }
    else if (avatarUser.equals("avatar4")) {
        imageUser_txt.setImageResource(R.drawable.avatar4) ;
    }
    else if (avatarUser.equals("avatar5")) {
        imageUser_txt.setImageResource(R.drawable.avatar5) ;
    }
    else if (avatarUser.equals("avatar6")) {
        imageUser_txt.setImageResource(R.drawable.avatar6) ;
    }
    else {
        imageUser_txt.setImageResource(R.drawable.avatar1) ;
    }

} else {
    imageLoader.displayImage(avatarUser, imageUser_txt, options);
}

imageUser_txt.bringToFront();
```

Comment: Did u get the solution to provide the border around the imageview android..Could u please help me..Thanks'

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a custom image view by extending ImageView. Use this ImageView in layout xml file using following code you can create white bar around image view

```
public class CustomImageView extends ImageView {
private Context myCtx;
private int borderSize = 6;
Bitmap bmp;
Bitmap bmpWithBorder;
private Drawable drawable;
public CustomImageView(Context context) {
super(context);
myCtx = context;
// TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
public CustomImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
super(context, attrs, defStyle);
myCtx = context;
}
public CustomImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
super(context, attrs);
myCtx = context;
}
/* (non-Javadoc)
* @see android.widget.ImageView#onDraw(android.graphics.Canvas)
*/
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
super.onDraw(canvas);
try{
drawable = getDrawable();
bmp = ((BitmapDrawable)drawable).getBitmap() ;
bmpWithBorder = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp.getWidth() + borderSize * 2, bmp.getHeight() + borderSize * 2, bmp.getConfig());
canvas.drawBitmap(bmpWithBorder, 0 , 0 , null);
canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
Resources res = myCtx.getResources();
canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, borderSize, borderSize, null);
}
catch (NullPointerException e) {
// TODO: handle exception
e.printStackTrace();
}
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks, could you add an example for using this custom class ?

Comment: put this class in any package. Suppose your package is com.sample.example. Replace your Imageview in your layout folder with com.sample.example.CustomImageView

Comment: <com.sample.example.CustomImageView
                android:id="@+id/detail_annonce_image_user"
                android:layout_width="65dp"
                android:layout_height="65dp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="225dp"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/avatar1" />

Comment: I forget to say that is use Rounded image displayer from UIL. Is this code will be able to add a border around my rounded image view ? (I update the code)

Comment: You dont want to use your ImageView. Replace your ImageView with this custom image view

Answer (score 0):

Add padding and background to your ImageView. Padding will be the width of the border and background will be the color of it.

```
<ImageView
       android:id="@+id/detail_annonce_image_user"
       android:layout_width="65dp"
       android:layout_height="65dp"
       android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
       android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
       android:layout_marginTop="225dp"
       android:scaleType="centerCrop"
       android:src="@drawable/avatar1"
       android:padding="5dp"
       android:background="#ffffff" />
```

Comment: Thanks, but this code add a white border as a shape. I use a rounded imageview.

Comment: So you can try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27636855/how-to-make-round-image-border-to-imageview-programatically-android/27636878#27636878

Comment: Perfect ! Npw i have a border to my imageview but yet a problem : my image is so big and is not all visible into the rounded image. Which parameter must i adapt ?

Comment: I do not fully understand your problem. Try use different android:scaleType

Comment: i added the code from your link, and added layoutwidth and layout height to the element. The result is that i well have a rounded border created around my imageview, but my image into the imageview is so big. As if the layout width and height was ignored..

Comment: Check your layout_width and layout_height. Or show the code of the layout you use.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67712/discussion-between-wawanopoulos-and-degrigorash).